# Linq query that tests for existence in multiple lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have similar to the following data structures

```
var blueList = new []
    {
        new { Id = 1, Value = 1000 }, 
        new { Id = 2, Value = 1300 }, 
        new { Id = 3, Value = 1500 },
        new { Id = 5, Value = 2100 }
    }.ToList();

var redList = new []
    {
        new { Id = 1, Value = 600 }, 
        new { Id = 3, Value = 950 }, 
        new { Id = 4, Value = 1100 },
        new { Id = 5, Value = 1300 }
    }.ToList();

var greenList = new []
    {
        new { Id = 1, Value = 50 }, 
        new { Id = 2, Value = 180 }, 
        new { Id = 3, Value = 270 },
        new { Id = 4, Value = 430 },
        new { Id = 5, Value = 510 }
    }.ToList();

var colourList = new [] { blueList, redList, greenList }.ToList();
```

The colourList can contain an abritrary number of elements as well, they just happened to be named in this particular instance.

How do I construct a linq query that will give me a new list that just contains "Ids" that are in all groups in the list?

The following result excludes Id = 2 because it is not in the redList and Id = 4 because it isn't in the blueList. This is what I'm after.

```
var result = new []
    {
        new { Id = 1, Values = new [] { 1000, 600, 50 } },
        new { Id = 3, Values = new [] { 1500, 950, 270 } },
        new { Id = 5, Values = new [] { 2100, 1300, 510 } }
    };
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: When posing a question, which I rarely do, I try and make the question as short as possible as well as try and put it in a form that someone could easily copy and paste sections into a console app to test with. If no one responds with an answer I will add my solution.

Comment: so if you have a solution, why ask a question in the first place?

Comment: I'm writing a solution now. I have a feeling someone could come up with a short pithy linq query to get the required solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy:

```
var query = 
    colourList
        .Select(xs => xs.Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Values = Enumerable.Repeat(x.Value, 1),
        }))
        .Aggregate((xs, vs) =>
            from x in xs
            join v in vs on x.Id equals v.Id
            select new
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Values = x.Values.Concat(v.Values),
            });
```

I get this result on your sample data:

[image: result]

Of course you can extend `colorList` to contain as many sublists as you like.

Comment: It certainly works. Now I just have to get my head around why ;)

Comment: Good answer. Maybe easy to read, but you can't tell me that's easy to write, at least for the non-expert. :p

Comment: Accepting your answer as it is a single linq query. Your solution makes sense now and it's interesting because it's unlike how I would attack the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @ClintGood - Just think of `Aggregate` as a way to fold each value of a series into the next one. The `xs` is the accumulator and `vs` the next list. I do the join to create the next `xs` in the sequence. It kind of turns the logic of joining two lists into the logic of joining "n" lists.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work ok:

```
var ids = new List<int>();

if (colourList != null && colourList.Any())
{
    // Grab all ids from the first list
    ids = colourList[0].Select(c => c.Id).ToList();

    // Save only the intersection with each additional list
    ids = colourList.Aggregate(ids, (cl1, cl2) => 
        cl1.Intersect(cl2.Select(c => c.Id)).ToList());
}

Console.WriteLine("The common ids are: {0}", string.Join(", ", ids));
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came up with this one. It just took me a bit of time to get my head into the double !Any

```
var idsInAllColour =
    from colour in colourList
    from id in colour
    where colourList.All(cli => cli.Any(ci => ci.Id == id.Id))
    group id by id.Id;
```

Comment: You might want to look into [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): `!list.Any(x => condition)` is the same as `list.All(x => !condition)`. In your case, that's `where colourList.All(cli => cli.Any(ci => ci.Id == id.Id))`.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of that final `into g select g` part.

Comment: Thanks both for your improvements

Answer (score 1):

I did it in a two step process:

- Find the distinct IDs
- For each distinct ID, filter to the ids that are in all lists

  ```
  var distinctIds = colourList.SelectMany(o => o).Select(o => o.Id).Distinct();

  var matchingIds = distinctIds.Where(id => colourList.All(l => l.Select(o => o.Id).Contains(id)));
  ```

Then I read other answers and realized that you only need the distinct ids from the first list:

```
    var matchingIds = colourList
                        .First()
                        .Where(j => colourList
                                        .Skip(1)
                                        .All(l => l.Any(k => j.Id == k.Id))
                               )
                        .Select(j => j.Id);
```

Here's the .NET fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/4pPcDO

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution.:-

```
var result = colourList.SelectMany(x => x)
                       .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                       .Where(x => x.Count() == colourList.Count())
                       .Select(x => new { Id = x.Key, Values = String.Join(",", x.Select(z => z.Value)) });
```

Here is the complete [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z1EEL8).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one!

```
var commonIds =
    colorList.SelectMany(cList => cList, (c, id) => new {c, id})
             .Where(cList => !colorList.Any(c => c.All(cl => cl.Id != cList.id.Id)))
             .GroupBy(cList => cList.id.Id, cList => cList.id)
             .Select(cList => cList.Key)
             .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", commonIds));
```